# Invalid register in AVR loading an immediate into low registers but not high?

Tags: assembly, avr, cpu-registers

I am trying to write an assembly program to add two numbers (working with ATmega328P). The task requires adding the value in r5 (specifically 0x88) to the value in memory location 0x0260 and storing the result in memory location 0x0360. Here is what I have written so far:

```
.include "m328pdef.inc"
ldi r5, 0x88
lds r1, 0x0260
add r5, r1
sts 0x0360, r5
end: rjmp end
```

If I replace the register names with r16 and r18, the program works. However, when using r5, the program gives an "Invalid register" error.

What to do? The assignment requires using register number 5.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem.  When using the assembly tag, you're also supposed to add a tag for the particular CPU / architecture (here some ATmega32 I presume).

Comment: I edited the question title to help future readers with the same problem find it.  (As opposed to people using wrong syntax like `add eax, edx` with an AVR assembler, or the reverse, trying to use an x86 assembler with AVR syntax.)  It makes the answer seem obvious when put that way, but knowing the answer often helps to write useful question titles that cover the right scope for people looking for it.

Answer (score 3):

I googled a little bit and found out that LDI only works on the upper 16 registers - R16-R31. So I decided to do LDI stuff to r16 and then MOV it to r5.

Comment: Many instructions (especially with immediates like `ori` or [`subi`](http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/GUID-0EEBCE6A-A0BB-44A5-B14E-46C9D7F11BF5.html)) only have room for 4-bit register numbers and thus only work on the top 16 registers.  If you can, use high regs for temporaries.  e.g. `ldi r24, 0x88`/ ... / `add r1, r24` (or `add r24, r1` if you want to keep the load result around).  But yes, `ldi`/`mov` is a good way to get an immediate value into a low reg.